# $S = \left\{ x^* Ax\mid x \in C^n ,\ x^*x = 1 \right\} \implies S\;$ is compact and convex

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Let $\,A \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}\,$ and $\,S = \left\{ {{x^*}Ax \mid x \in \mathbb C^n,\ {x^*}x = 1} \right\}.\,$

Why is $A$  *compact* and *convex*?

Comment: This is known as the Toeplitz-Hausdorff theorem. Compactness is trivial. For convexity, see [this AMS "shorter note"](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-01/S0002-9939-1970-0262849-9/S0002-9939-1970-0262849-9.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding compacity**

$R = \left\{x \in \mathbb C^n  \mid x^*x =1 \right\}$ is bounded and closed as the reverse image of the closed subset $\{1\}$ by a continuous function. Hence $R$ is compact.

$S$ is the image of the compact $R$ by the continuous map $x \mapsto x^* A x$. Hence is compact.

***Regarding convexity***

Consider the second derivative of $t \mapsto ((1-t) x +t y)^* A ((1-t) x +t y)$.

You don't have additional hypothesis on $A$?